# PHP - How to access Twilio in a composer namespace environment

Tags: php, composer-php, ratchet, twilio-php

I've been working with Rachet WebSockets and created a simple chat application. The example uses a WebSocket namespace. This is my first time using namespace. Now I'm trying to add Twilio service but can seem to add Twilio to my namespace.

I know it is autoloaded in the autoload_files.php

```
<?php

// autoload_files.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    $vendorDir . '/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php',
);
```

In the composer.json file

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Websocket": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.3",
        "twilio/sdk": "^4.5"
    }
}
```

I followed the steps from this website : https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php#using-without-composer

I'm calling twilio inside a method of my class like this:

```
$AccountSid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$message = $client->account->messages->create(array( 
    'To' => "+555555555", 
    'From' => "+555555555", 
    'Body' => "This is a test",   
));
```

Keep getting this error: `Uncaught Error: Class 'Websocket\Client' not found in ......`

I'm very new to composer and namespace, hope this is enough information to help me.

Comment: The interesting part is: Why do you link to that website at the "using-without-composer" anchor when you ARE using Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to update Twilio,

ran `composer require twilio/sd`

```
- Removing twilio/sdk (4.12.0)
- Installing twilio/sdk (5.4.1)
Downloading: 100%
```

Now I'm able to `use Twilio\Rest\Client;` since it was missing before.

Answer (score 0):

When using namespaces, PHP will always start looking for classes which aren't prepended with their own namespace in the current one.

In your case the current namespace would be `Websocket`, thus PHP is trying to autoload the class `Websocket\Client`, to prevent this, you have two options :

1) Tell PHP where to look by using `use` :

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
```

2) Prepend the correct namespace

```
$client = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);
```

Comment: tried `$client = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);`  and it says `Class 'Twilio\Rest\Client' not found` Do i need to add twilio to my autoload_psr4 or  autoload_namespace?